# Navigate in Xcode between UI to is related controller and from controller to UI

Tags: swift, xcode, navigation

In the Android Studio, every view have a separate file and user can go from Java file to its view file by click on this

```
setViewContant(R.layout.my_view);
```

Is there is any way in Xcode that can take user form `viewController.swift` to is related layout file. Because it's totally Spaghetti in `Main.Storyboard`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't remember a better way than just search the ViewController class name.

1. Right-click on the ViewController class name
2. Select "Find Selected Text in Workspace"

[image: search ViewController name]

3. In the left panel will appear the list of files which have occurrences of the searched word
4. Select the entry in your storyboard

[image: select storyboard viewcontroller]

---

btw: I would suggest to split the Main.storyboard in smaller ones! ;)